# MongoDB - Updating a nested document

Tags: mongodb

I'm wanting to update the nested 'crawled' to True within the appropriate document with the specified URL.

I'm fairly new to mongodb and I just can't seem to figure this out, any help is much appreciated.

## collection structure

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e9978732beb44a2f2ac6ae"
    },
    "domain": "techweekeurope.co.uk",
    "good": [
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "/workspace/microsoft-dell-windows-surface-106648"
        },
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "/workspace/new-street-view-images-raise-privacy-concerns-5850"
        },
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "/workspace/quiz-of-the-week-dell-reborn-106744"
        }
    ],
    "bad": [],
    "link_found": false,
    "subdomain": "http://www.",
    "crawled": true
}
```

## update query

```
self.collection.update({'good.link':'/workspace/microsoft-dell-windows-surface-106648'}, {'crawled': True})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first document search with link and in second document set updated value. You need to specify good.$.crawled to specify that element of array to update.

```
.update(
        {'good.link':'/workspace/microsoft-dell-windows-surface-106648'}, 
        {
          $set : {'good.$.crawled': true} 
        }
)
```

Comment: [For reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said first and it wasn't working but I've just seen your edit and it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help, answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to query for specific entries in an array of a document.   Once you have matched it, you can use `$set` to change the value

This example is for `find` but it works with update as well.

```
db.survey.find(
   { results: { $elemMatch: { product: "xyz", score: { $gte: 8 } } } }
)
```

Comment: There is only one query condition. No need to use $elemMatch for that.